# Tableau report, using filter as soon as the report is opened

Tags: tableau-api

I am developing reports using tableau. I want the report in such a way that when the user opens the report it should first show him a filter to select which country data he is looking for. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about a prompt or something?
Just add a filter/parameter? What if he wants to change it to another country and the prompt is gone?